# Remove an EventListener when a certain function runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function setEvents() {
  // do some code
  myValidation();
}

function myValidation() {
 // do some checks
 // if checks passed, then set the values to URL parameters
 window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?myName=" + capture_name);
}

setEvents();

$( "#edit-submitted-name-consolidation" ).click(function() {

   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
     (e || window.event).returnValue = setEvents();           
   }, false);

});
```

**Explanation:**

My code above calls the `setEvent()` function which calls a `myValidation()` function from within.

Also, I have a code, `beforeunload` ,to run the same function when the user closes the browser. This only happens when a certain input gets clicked.

However, I want the `myValidation()` not to run this `beforeunload`.

So in other words, I want the browser to always run the `beforeunload` , but when `myValidation()` is being called / used, the `beforeunload` should be removed.

So to achieve that, **this is what I tried**:

```
function setEvents() {
  // do some code
  myValidation();
}

function myValidation() {
 // do some checks
 // if checks passed, then set the values to URL parameters
 window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",(e));
 window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?myName=" + capture_name);
}

setEvents();

$( "#edit-submitted-name-consolidation" ).click(function() {
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
     (e || window.event).returnValue = setEvents();           
   }, false);
});
```

So, I added `window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",(e));` in `myValidation()`. However, this is not working for me.

So may I ask, how do I remove than `beforeunload` if `myValidation()` is being used?

Comment: You need a reference to use `removeEventListener`.

Comment: Yes I did, in my question, you can see under what I tried, in the `myValidation()` i did run this code `window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",(e));` But its not working

Comment: I'm not sure if the way I wrote `window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",(e));` is correct.

Comment: It's not. Your unbinding an anonymous, empty function. Totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you should extract the handler into a variable, because these are two separate functions, you got to have a reference to the original, you cannot remove the listener like this.

What you are doing right now is removing an event listener which is not there.

```
const handler = function(e){
  (e || window.event).returnValue = setEvents();           
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler, false);
window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
```

For further explanation: try this =>

```
const x = () => {}
const y = () => {}

console.log(x === y) // should be true right? wrong. functions are compared by reference.
console.log(x === x) // this is true, since the reference is the same
```

Comment: I'm not getting the result. I placed the addEvent at where my beforeunload is and I placed the removeAddevent inside myValidation(), but its not working for me. It still creates a pop up when redirecting to create URL parameters.

Comment: It doesnt matter where you put it, the point is, that you defined your callback in addEventListerer, and removeEventListener separately, don't do that

Comment: Then your code has other problems. This is definitely how you add removable listeners.

Comment: Sorry I am still trying, will update accordingly. I tried to put the addlistener to the onclick event, and on myValidation tried to remove it, but its not working. So I will check my code to see if I made an error.

Comment: @DanielTok I understand it now. I tried to look at your code and yes you are right, basically I was setting the const handler inside a click function, so I was getting it wrong. I put it out like a global variable and then called for add or remove events and now it works. Thank you very much!